# the commend Input.GetKey isn't working in my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a 2d platformer and the player can walk or run.
When I press Lshift the speed Multiplier isn't changing for some reason.
this is my player movement (it's called in the Update() function):

```
 private void WalkRun()
{
    _inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_inputX * _moveSpeed * _speedMultiplier, _rb.velocity.y);

    _Run = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

    if (_Run && _grounded)
        _speedMultiplier = 2f;
    else
        _speedMultiplier = 1f;
}
```

'

thanks to the helpers :)

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html), "Returns true *WHILE THE USER HOLDS DOWN THE KEY* identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter".  SUGGESTION: https://gamedevbeginner.com/input-in-unity-made-easy-complete-guide-to-the-new-system/

Comment: Did you check `_grounded`? Your code workly

Answer (score 0):

The Input.GetKey(KeyCode) method means: GetKey returns true when the key specified by name is held down by the user. Does the "_grounded" object not work? You can try the following code.

```
 private float speed = 10f;//Initial speed
 public bool isPPP = false;//This is a detected state
 public Toggle to;//UI
 public Text toText;//Text


 void Update() {
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    ChangeSpeed();//Call the method of state detection
    if (isPPP == false)//Judging that this state is the initial speed
    {
       
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            float ratio = v * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(ratation, 0, ratation);
        }
    }
    if(isPPP == true)//This state is the newly given speed
    {
        float speed = 50f;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            float ratio = v * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(ratation, 0, ratation);
        }
    }
}
// method to detect state and change state
public void WalkRun()
{
    if (isPPP == false)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift && _grounded))
        {
            to.GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn = true;
            toText.text = "Wind Walk";
            toText.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
            isPPP = true;
        }
    }
    else if (isPPP == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift && _grounded))
        {
            to.GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn = false;
            toText.text = "Walk";
            toText.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.green;
            isPPP = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is _grounded:                                                                                                         _grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_groundCheck.position, _groundCheckRadius, _groundLayer);
but it's working. I don't think its the problem because when I debug when I press lshift its entering the if statement but doesn't effect the _speedMultiplier for some reason

Comment: @yam kabakov I re-edited the code. It should be possible to change the speed.